# string index out of bounds error in java (charAt)

Tags: java, charat

Quick question. I have this code in a program:

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any word below")
int i = 0;  
for (int j = 0; j <= input.length(); j++)  
{
    System.out.print(input.charAt(i));  
    System.out.print(" "); //don't ask about this.  
    i++;
}
```

- Input being user input
- `i` being integer with value of 0, as seen

Running the code produces this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
>   at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
>   at program.main(program.java:15)

If I change the `charAt` `int` to 0 instead of `i`, it does not produce the error...
what can be done? What is the problem?

Comment: why do you use i in your loop? couldn't you use j?

Comment: in this case I am using i as a counting integer, as they do in for loops, as I didnt expect to use a for loop, and then I did...

Comment: I would vote for the other replies, but I do not have the required rep yet

Comment: Thanks to all of you for helping me with this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace:

```
j <= input.length()
```

... with ...

```
j < input.length()
```

Java `String` character indexing is 0-based, so your loop termination condition should be at `input`'s length - 1.

Currently, when your loop reaches the penultimate iteration before termination, it references `input` character at an index equal to `input`'s length, which throws the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` (a `RuntimeException`).

Answer (score 3):

String indexing in Java (like any other array-like structure) is **zero-based**. This means that `input.charAt(0)` is the leftmost character. The last character is then at `input.charAt(input.length() - 1)`.

So you are referencing one too many elements in your `for` loop. Replace `<=` with `<` to fix. The alternative (`<= input.length() - 1`) could bite you hard if you ever port your code to C++ (which has unsigned types).

By the way, the Java runtime emits extremely helpful exceptions and error messages. Do learn to read and understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Replace for loop condition `j <= input.length()` with `j < input.length()` , as string in Java follows zero based indexing.
e.g. indexing for the String `"india"` would start from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

You were accessing the array from [0-length], you should do it from [0-(length-1)]

```
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++)
{
    System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
    System.out.print(" "); //don't ask about this.
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
j< input.length()
```

and then:

```
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++)
{
    System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
    System.out.print(" "); //don't ask about this.
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++)
{
    System.out.print(input.charAt(j));
    System.out.print(" "); //don't ask about this.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++)
{
    System.out.print(input.charAt(j));
    System.out.print(" "); //don't ask about this.
}
```